# Swift - WatchKit: How to get data back to the root view controller?

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-6

Suppose I have three interface controllers which are all linked by push segues.

`InterfaceController1` -pushSegue-> `InterfaceController2` -pushSegue-> `InterfaceController3`

InterfaceController1 has table which will house the data from the class below.

So, suppose I have class:

```
class manageData {
    var data1:String?
    var data2:String? 
}
```

and this class is supposed to hold the data from `InterfaceController2` and `InterfaceController3`.

So InterfaceController1 creates a `manageData` object and passes it to InterfaceController2 using the `contextForSegueWIthIdentifier` method. InterfaceController2 then adds to its data to the manageData object and passes it along to InterfaceController3 using the `contextForSegueWIthIdentifier` method as well.

Now my question is, once InterfaceController3 adds its data to the object, how do I pass that complete object back to InterfaceController1 with the data filled in so InterfaceController1 can add the data to the table? Hopefully I've made this clear enough. I don't have any actual code to represent this because I have no idea how to implement it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way I solved this issue was to create a singleton class which held all my data throughout the different controllers. Then when I reach the last controller and send my data to the singleton, I pop back to the root controller.

When I'm back in the root controller, in the awake method, I call a function I made called `loadTableData()` which automatically takes information from the singleton when it awakes and loads it in the table. Seems to work perfectly for now but I don't know any potential issues that can come up with this method.